# Modificar este codigo js para que se ejecute cada un par de minutos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código, que hace que cuando das click en cualquier parte de la página se abra una ventana con otra página, por ejemplo de publicidad, pero lo hace siempre, quiero que lo haga cuando se entra, y por ejemplo despues de 2 minutos que se está en la página sin hacer click.

```js
 <script>
function PopUP(){
window.open('https://publicidad.com','_blank'); //abrir nueva ventana
document.focus(); //poner el foco en la ventana actual
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `setInterval` con el tiempo en milisegundos, por ejemplo:

```
<body onload="setInterval(PopUp(),120000)">
```